# How to get my Java 'if' statement to work?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, syntax-error

I am very new to learning Java and currently I am working on a program that lets me fight the computer based on simple stats that I have assigned us and a random number to function as a dice roll. I recognize that there may be numerous other problems with my code, but the main issue I am trying to resolve is the "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens" on line 84 and the "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement" on line 77.

I don't see what the issue is. What am I doing wrong? Both issues are listed near the bottom of my code in comments next to their corresponding lines.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Fight {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String you = keyboard.next();
        int youWounds = 1;
        int youTough = 4;
        int youAttack = 1;
        int youWS = 4;
        int youAS = 3;

        String Comp = "Bad Guy";
        int compWounds = 1;
        int compTough = 4;
        int compAttack = 1;
        int compWS = 4;
        int compAS = 3;

    System.out.println(you + ", do you want to FIGHT?!?!?");
    System.out.println("Yes / No?");

    String inputString = keyboard.next();       

    if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("FIGHT!!!!");
        while (youWounds > 0 && compWounds > 0) {

            int youRan = new Random().nextInt(6)+1; // this is where you roll to hit 
            System.out.println(you + " rolls " + youRan +" to hit");

            if (youRan >= 7-youWS) { // this is the logic for roll to hit 
                System.out.println(you +" hit");

                int youRanTW = new Random().nextInt(6)+1; // this is where you check to see if your hit wounds 
                System.out.println(you + " rolls " + youRanTW +" to wound");
                if (youRanTW > compTough) { // this is the logic for roll to wound
                    System.out.println(you+" wounds"+Comp);
                    compWounds = compWounds - 1; // this is where comp loses a wound
                    if (compWounds <= 0) { // this is the logic for wound loss
                        System.out.println(Comp+" dies!!!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("But, "+Comp+" fights on!");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(you=" does not wound");
                }
            } else { 
                System.out.println(you +" misses");
            }

            int compRan = new Random().nextInt(6)+1;
            System.out.println(Comp+" rolls " + compRan + " to hit");

            if (compRan >= 7-compWS) { // this is the logic for roll to hit 
                System.out.println(Comp +" hit");                       
                int compRanTW = new Random().nextInt(6)+1; // this is where you check to see if your hit wounds 
                System.out.println(Comp + " rolls " + compRanTW +" to wound");
                if (compRanTW > youTough) { // this is the logic for roll to wound
                    System.out.println(Comp+" wounds"+you);
                    youWounds = youWounds - 1; // this is where you loses a wound
                    if (youWounds <= 0) { // this is the logic for wound loss
                        System.out.println(you+" dies!!!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("But, "+you+" fights on!");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(Comp=" does not wound");
                }                   
            } else {
                System.out.println(Comp +" misses");
            }
        } else { // this is wher I get "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement". The "}" is underlined in red on my screen
            if (youWounds <=0){
                System.out.println(Comp+" WINS!!!!");
            } else {
                System.out.println(you+" WINS!!!!");
            }
        }
    } else { // this is where i get "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens". it wants me to delete "} else".
        System.out.println(you + " you are a looser!!!!!!!!");
    }
    keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your indentation, you have an `else` block that matches up with your `while` block, which you can't do.

Comment: @doelleri so how do I create an else condition for when the criteria in the entail while condition is no longer true?

Comment: You should really really avoid those nested ifs... The code gets a lot harder to read and consequently harder to maintain and spot bugs. For starters, try extracting some well named methods, such as verifyPlayerHit or something...

Comment: Btw, while conditions do not have an else statement, when the condition is false it simply moves out of the loop and into the next line after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the flow of your program, but the current problem is that you are trying to use `else` on your `while` loop.  This is not possible or necessary.

The `while` loop will continue until the defined condition is met. Once that happens, the `while` loop ends and the next line of code is executed.

So, remove the `else {` from the closing of the `while` loop.  You can then just evaluate the results.

Here's the corrected code, with a couple comments to show WHERE to remove things:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fight {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String you = keyboard.next();
        int youWounds = 1;
        int youTough = 4;
        int youAttack = 1;
        int youWS = 4;
        int youAS = 3;

        String Comp = "Bad Guy";
        int compWounds = 1;
        int compTough = 4;
        int compAttack = 1;
        int compWS = 4;
        int compAS = 3;

        System.out.println(you + ", do you want to FIGHT?!?!?");
        System.out.println("Yes / No?");

        String inputString = keyboard.next();

        if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("FIGHT!!!!");
            while (youWounds > 0 && compWounds > 0) {

                int youRan = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1; // this is where you roll to hit
                System.out.println(you + " rolls " + youRan + " to hit");

                if (youRan >= 7 - youWS) { // this is the logic for roll to hit
                    System.out.println(you + " hit");

                    int youRanTW = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1; // this is where you check to see if your hit wounds
                    System.out.println(you + " rolls " + youRanTW + " to wound");
                    if (youRanTW > compTough) { // this is the logic for roll to wound
                        System.out.println(you + " wounds" + Comp);
                        compWounds = compWounds - 1; // this is where comp loses a wound
                        if (compWounds <= 0) { // this is the logic for wound loss
                            System.out.println(Comp + " dies!!!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("But, " + Comp + " fights on!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(you = " does not wound");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(you + " misses");
                }

                int compRan = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                System.out.println(Comp + " rolls " + compRan + " to hit");

                if (compRan >= 7 - compWS) { // this is the logic for roll to hit
                    System.out.println(Comp + " hit");
                    int compRanTW = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1; // this is where you check to see if your hit wounds
                    System.out.println(Comp + " rolls " + compRanTW + " to wound");
                    if (compRanTW > youTough) { // this is the logic for roll to wound
                        System.out.println(Comp + " wounds" + you);
                        youWounds = youWounds - 1; // this is where you loses a wound
                        if (youWounds <= 0) { // this is the logic for wound loss
                            System.out.println(you + " dies!!!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("But, " + you + " fights on!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(Comp = " does not wound");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(Comp + " misses");
                }
            }  // REMOVE THE ELSE AND BRACKET
            if (youWounds <= 0) {
                System.out.println(Comp + " WINS!!!!");
            } else {
                System.out.println(you + " WINS!!!!");
            }
            // REMOVE THIS BRACKET
        } else { // this is where i get "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens". it wants me to delete "} else".
            System.out.println(you + " you are a looser!!!!!!!!");
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please specifically change the original code to reflect the missing closing brackets? I'm not sure where in my code I have missed these brackets. Also, is there a way I can format my code in Eclipse to show how my if, while, and so on statements are nested? Something like a line that goes from the start of a statement to where the compiler sees it closing?

Comment: The code I posted IS your original code. But I will edit and add comments where I added the brackets.

Comment: I am not sure how Eclipse visualizes nesting. I know in IntelliJ IDEA, I have exactly that vertical line. Also, clicking on a bracket will highlight the matching opening/closing bracket.  Does Eclipse to that for you?